# TFTP Server not receiving from Client

Tags: c++, client, tftp

I am developing a TFTP Server using C++. The problem is that I cannot receive or at least I do not see anything in the receiving buffer when I use a TFTP Client Demo (HS TFTP) which is available over the internet.

I can 'sense' that my app is receiving something, but I cannot see what was received when I use that demo for TFTP Client. 
So, what I did was to create a client myself and send a command like 'WRQ'. In this way I am able to receive the command which was sent. Thus I do not have an idea why I cannot see what is coming from a regular TFTP Client that can be found on the internet.

BTW the transmission had been held in the same computer using the local ip 127.0.0.1 and default TFTP IP 69.

Comment: Too vague. Explain where the client is, where the server is. Firewalls in the middle? What addresses? Show your code.

Answer (score 2):

Troubleshooting your scenario requires of Wireshark.
You can then quickly visually spot what might be going on with the TFTP protocol.